# Navigate to a screen not defined with createBottomTabNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate to a screen that I have not defined with `createBottomTabNavigation` as I don't want it to be shown on the bottom tab navigation.

To try so I have created the component separately:

```
class SingleScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is sigle screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

To navigate to this screen:

```
render () {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return(
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('SingleScreen', {id: 'id', from: 'Search'})}>
    //Code
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

But is not working. Do I have to describe this screen with `createBottomTabNavigator`? If so, is it possible to hide from appearing on the tab bar?

Comment: In order to navigate to a screen, yes it has to be part the whole navigation system. @Vishal Dhanotiya's answer is correct except you have to wrap that navigation somewhere with `createAppContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some change in app.js. add createBottomTabNavigator inside createStackNavigator. Add those component into stacknavigator in which you do not want to add into bottom tab navigator. In createBottomTabNavigator add those component which you want to show in tab bar

Please check following code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import LoginScreen from "./Screens/LoginScreen";
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StackNav />;
  }
}
const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabNavigator: {
      screen: AppTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    SingleScreen: {
      screen: SingleScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    SecondScreen: {
      screen: SecondScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "TabNavigator"
  }
);
const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  }
});
```